# Displaying inner area and removing outside area when clicking on layer in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I want to display multiple WFS layers on OSM layer.

If i selected any one layer from multiple layers then display only that layer inside area and cut or remove the outside area of selected layer.

Can anyone give me sample example to do this in OpenLayers 3?

Comment: You may need layer spy example http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-spy.html

Comment: Thanks,I wan't to display  all the layers by default ,after click on layer then      display inside the layer and remove out side area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem,I got this link from internet:

http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html

but this link only displays for one cropping layer.

Comment: Update for Seema's answer since that link recently died, you can now find the demo here: [http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html)